# OpenCV CMake выдаёт ошибку

Tags: opencv, cmake

Пытаюсь сделать конфигурацию в CMake, чтобы попробовать дескриптор Surf в OpenCV c++, но CMake выдаёт ошибку

```
calib3d
   core
 > cudaarithm
 > cudabgsegm
 > cudacodec
 > cudafeatures2d
 > cudafilters
 > cudaimgproc
 > cudalegacy
 > cudaobjdetect
 > cudaoptflow
 > cudastereo
 > cudawarping
 > cudev
   dnn
   features2d
   flann
   highgui
   imgcodecs
   imgproc
   java
   js
   ml
   objdetect
   photo
   python
 > shape
   stitching
 > superres
   ts
   video
   videoio
 > videostab
 > viz
   world
 > xfeatures2d
   aruco
   bgsegm
   bioinspired
   ccalib
   cnn_3dobj
 > cudaarithm
 > cudabgsegm
 > cudacodec
 > cudafeatures2d
 > cudafilters
 > cudaimgproc
 > cudalegacy
 > cudaobjdetect
 > cudaoptflow
 > cudastereo
 > cudawarping
 > cudev
   cvv
   datasets
   dnn_objdetect
   dnn_superres
   dpm
   face
   freetype
   fuzzy
   hdf
   hfs
   img_hash
   line_descriptor
   matlab
   optflow
   ovis
   phase_unwrapping
   plot
   quality
   reg
   rgbd
   saliency
   sfm
 > shape
   stereo
   structured_light
 > superres
   surface_matching
   text
   tracking
 > videostab
 > viz
 > xfeatures2d
   ximgproc
   xobjdetect
   xphoto

CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:352 (message):
  Duplicated modules NAMES has been found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:370 (_assert_uniqueness)
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Кажется я нашёл ответ, проблема в том, что версии не совпадают, и видимо нужно обновить opencv и скачать opencv и opencv_contrib из одного места